# Rotation with custom modal UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, modalviewcontroller, transition

I'm currently displaying a modal view controller using a custom animator. It's all working perfectly fine, however, when I present the modal view controller and then rotate the device, the presented modal view controller does not resize accordingly.

From reading Apple's docs and various other stack overflow posts, it's clear that the `UITransitionView` is not meant to rotate by design according to Apple. This is fine, however, what is the suggested behavior for developers when a rotation occurs during a modal (when the modal view controllers view is on the transition view's content view)?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this but overriding the method `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` on my presenting view controller.

Though this might not be the correct way of doing it, it works and is something that Apple hasn't addressed in their documentation, so I'm happy with this fix.

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
}
```